# 'Type' has kind '*' - Haskell

Tags: haskell

In my code which is a rather simple case function whereby if a 'tool' is 'nothing' then go to the next tool, so on, so forth. :

```
nextTool :: Tool -> Tool
  nextTool l = 
      case l == nothing of
        LineTool nothing -> PolygonTool nothing
        PolygonTool [] -> CircleTool nothing
        CircleTool nothing -> TriangleTool nothing
        TriangleTool nothing -> RectangleTool 1.0 nothing
        RectangleTool 1.0 nothing -> CapTool nothing
        CapTool nothing -> LineTool nothing
        _ -> nextTool
```

But I have this error which states:

```
• Expected kind ‘k0 -> k1 -> *’, but ‘Tool’ has kind ‘*’

• In an expression type signature: Tool -> Tool nextTool l
  In the expression:
      otherwise == "Error" nextTool :: Tool -> Tool nextTool l
  In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                 an equation for ‘nextColour’:
      otherwise == "Error" nextTool :: Tool -> Tool nextTool l
```

Here, `Tool` is defined as:

```
data Tool 
  = LineTool (Maybe Point) 
  | PolygonTool [Point] 
  | CircleTool (Maybe Point) 
  | TriangleTool (Maybe Point) 
  | RectangleTool Double (Maybe Point) 
  | CapTool (Maybe Point) (Maybe Point) 
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

I am clueless as to what this means. Could someone tell me what it means and the required fix for it please?

Comment: when you write `nothing` do you mean `Nothing`? (notice the capital N). Also when you write, `case l == nothing of ... `  that's a boolean value, therefore the cases are `True` of `False`. Also, the error says `otherwise == "Error"` which doesn't appear in your code snnipet. Also, indentation is wrong, `nextTool` should be in the same column. By the way it seems that your error is related with indentation too.

Comment: There is an indentation problem. Align the second line to the same column as the first line. On top of that this code may or may not have other problems. It is difficult to tell without having a [mcve].

Comment: I am clueless as to what your code means. This code doesn't make sense. You are saying that if `l == nothing` is a `LineTool` then return a `PolygonTool` etc. But how can `l == nothing` be a `LineTool`? It's a boolean!

Comment: Please show the definition of `Tool` as well

Comment: data Tool
  = LineTool (Maybe Point)  
  | PolygonTool [Point]
  | CircleTool (Maybe Point)
  | TriangleTool (Maybe Point)
  | RectangleTool Double (Maybe Point)
  | CapTool (Maybe Point) (Maybe Point)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

Comment: I think you need to clarify your Haskell knowledge a little bit. The code makes very little sense, hopefully the answer by @leftaroundbout helps you!

Answer (score 6):

Because you indented the `nextTool l = ...`, your code is parsed as

```
(nextTool :: Tool -> (Tool
  nextTool l)) = 
      case l == nothing of ...
```

or, with different alignment

```
(nextTool :: Tool -> (Tool nextTool l))
  = case l == nothing of ...
```

That doesn't make any sense of course, but surprisingly enough this style *is* in principle a valid way of defining a function. (See explanation below.)

What you tried to write instead was

```
nextTool :: Tool -> Tool
nextTool l = ...
```

You seem to have another indentation error in the preceding function in your file, which is why `otherwise == "Error"` appears in the error message.

Both `otherwise == "Error"` and your `case` construct with `l == nothing` don't make any sense either. You normally have `otherwise` in guards, but then it needs to be `| otherwise  = "Error"` (notice the single `=`). And `nothing` is a variable name at this point that's probably not even defined; even if it were defined (or if you meant `Nothing`, which would however have the wrong type), the result of `l == nothing` would be a boolean, i.e. not something you can match on those tool-constructors.

I think what you wanted to write was simply

```
nextTool :: Tool -> Tool
nextTool (LineTool n) = PolygonTool n
nextTool (PolygonTool []) = CircleTool Nothing
nextTool (CircleTool n) = TriangleTool n
nextTool (TriangleTool n) = RectangleTool 1.0 n
nextTool (RectangleTool _ n) = CapTool n
nextTool (CapTool n) = LineTool n
```

This is probably still wrong, but can't be answered better since you didn't provide the definition of your `Tool` type.

---

So, why did your original code not just give some parse error or something else that made it clear that the indentation was wrong? What was that about *kind*s?

Well, because `nextTool` and `l` appear as lowercase identifiers in the signature, the compiler treats them as implicitly quantified type variables, and you're defining simply a constant called `nextTool` which is supposed to have the (nonsensical) type `Tool -> Tool nextTool l`. That type is what caused the error GHC gave you: in order to have `Tool nextTool l` (regardless of what `nextTool` and `l` are), `Tool` needs to have a kind of the form `k -> l -> m`. An example of a type that matches this would be the standard

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

Here we have

```
ghci> :k Either
Either :: Type -> Type -> Type
```

(in older GHC it is `* -> * -> *`, which means the same). This kind means that the `Either` type constructor should be applied to two types, in order to give you the complete variant type.

```
foo :: Either Int Double -> Double
foo (Left i) = fromIntegral i
foo (Right n) = negate n
```

But `Tool` is not of this form, it is simple

```
ghci> :k Tool
Tool :: Type
```

i.e. you can't apply it to any arguments, whether concrete ones like in `foo` above or implicitly quantified ones like `nextTool` and `l` in your code.

Comment: The type for 'Tool' is data Tool
  = LineTool (Maybe Point)  
  | PolygonTool [Point]
  | CircleTool (Maybe Point)
  | TriangleTool (Maybe Point)
  | RectangleTool Double (Maybe Point)
  | CapTool (Maybe Point) (Maybe Point)
  deriving (Eq, Show)